# How to get specific value from input form that generated by echo Table from database mysql in PHP?

Tags: php

How to get specific value from input form that generated by echo in PHP?
the input form is auto generated according to the indicator table called from mysql.
when submitted, the value of the 2 inputs of the achievement will appear in each indicator. I want 1 indicator, 1 achievement value.
This is my code :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){ 

$_SESSION['id_kpi']=$row[0];
echo '<tr>
        <td>
            <span class="textarea" role="textbox" name="kpi'. ++$n .'" contenteditable>'.$row[1].'</span>
        
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="margin-left:30px;">
            <input type="text" name="achievement[]" id="achievement" style="width:30%">
            </span>
        </td>
        
    </tr>';

    
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
{       

$idkpi = $row[0];

$achi = $_POST['achievement'];

$items = array();
for($i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++){
  $items[$i] = array(  
    "achieve"       => $achi[$i]
  );
}

$value = array();
foreach($items as $item){
  $value[] = "('{$item['achieve']}')";
}

$values = implode(", ", $value);

echo 'Your value is '.$values. '<br>';

}
```

**Result**
The result is value of the 2 inputs of the achievement will appear in each indicator. And this result is not what i want. Please check the image.
[View Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPDTj.png)

Answer (score 0):

After foreach of $items you don't need to create another array and implode that. Just put echo in foreach loop. Like:

```
foreach($items as $item){
  echo "Your value is (' $item['achieve'] ')<br>";
}
```

I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: your code is okay, but still more or less the same as before. please refer to this image [link](https://imgur.com/a/UgaX3we)

Comment: Can I know   "while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query))", in here what is the result of $row? Just print_r($row) is good to me.

Comment: i call it to display table from mysql database. each table (indicator) has an input form (achievement). The problem is as mentioned in the post above. if there is more table, then more input form is generated.

Comment: if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
{       

$idkpi = $row[0];

$achi = $_POST['achievement'];

for($i = 0 ; $i <  count($achi) ; $i++){
 echo 'Your value is '.$achi[$i]. '<br>';
}

}    hope this will solve the issue. Please check this and let me know.

Comment: it's still the same. 2 value in each achievement. I think I will leave this method and switch to another method that has been tested. Thank you so much for your suggestion and help.

Comment: I don't understand why are you leave this method. But if you need to solve this issue, you can knock me. Thank you.